# Top results from multiple elections in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, view

I have a table with votes from multiple sectors (think of each sector as a state or similar) on multiple candidates. Each sector has multiple candidates, each with a different vote count.

Here is my table (simplified)

```
CREATE TABLE [Results]
(
    [SectorID] BIGINT,
    [CanditateID] BIGINT, 
    [VoteCount] BIGINT,
    [Newness] DATETIME
)
```

I obviously keep sector and candidate meta data in another table, but I need to find the highest voted candidate for each sector, so I can join those tables into a view.

The best candidate in each sector, is determined by `[VoteCount]`, and if there are two with the same number of votes, it is determined by `[Newness]`. There must remain exactly one line per sector, and I have to be able to use it in a view, joined together with the meta data.

How do I obtain the highest voted candidate from each sector?

Comment: You really need BigInt?   BigInt X BigInt is a really big number.

Comment: Yes I know, and yes I need. I may change it later, but so far I am told to expect A LOT of data. It's not just a hobby project this, and the above is just named as it is to make it easier for you guys to relate to :) When I wrote the above, I guess I just left it there out of laziness :)

Comment: Removed the stuff about indexing on the view from the question, as I realized that this is impossible. Closed the question with the most popular solution chosen. Both current solutions work however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you are using SQL Server 2005 or greater, you want to do this with `row_number()`:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by SectorId order by VoteCount desc, Newness desc) as seqnum
      from Results r
     ) r
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Seems I was a bit hasty with this one. Should have thought more about the question. This works, but I cannot index on it.

Answer (score 2):

This would work and can be joined:

```
SELECT 
    TR.SectorID, TR.CandidateID
FROM
    tblResults TR
    INNER JOIN ...
    INNER JOIN ...
WHERE CandidateID =
(
    SELECT TOP 1 CandidateID
    FROM tblResults TRSUB
    WHERE TRSUB.SectorID = TR.SectorID
    ORDER BY VoteCount DESC, Newness DESC
)
```